# Scaled/weighted density plot

Tags: r, frequency-distribution

I want to generate a density plot of observed temperatures that is scaled by the number of events observed for each temperature data point. My data contains two columns: Temperature and Number [of observations].

Right now, I have a density plot that only incorporates the Temperature frequency according to:

```
plot(density(Temperature, na.rm=T), type="l", bty="n")
```

How do I scale this density to account for the Number of observations at each temperature? For example, I want to be able to see the temperature density plot scaled to show if there are greater/fewer observations for each temperature at higher/lower temperatures.

I think I'm looking for something that could weight the temperatures?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

And to do this in base (using DanM's data):

```
plot(density(dat$Temperature,weights=dat$Number/sum(dat$Number),na.rm=T),type='l',bty='n')
```

Answer (score 19):

I think you can get what you want by passing a `weights` argument to `density`. Here's an example using `ggplot`

```
dat <- data.frame(Temperature = sort(runif(10)), Number = 1:10)
ggplot(dat, aes(Temperature)) + geom_density(aes(weights=Number/sum(Number)))
```

Comment: __2017 Update:__ the aesthetic has been renamed `weight` without  `s`, so that the plotting instruction becomes: `ggplot(dat, aes(x = Temperature, weight = Number/sum(Number))) + geom_density()`.

Comment: Also, I don't think it is necessary to scale the weights to 1 yourself, ggplto2 seems to do it, can just use  `weight = Number`